# Instalar glashfish o payara en eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

No se puede instalar glasfish desde Marketplace

- No se instala nada
- El proyecto dice qie esta inactivo https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools.glassfish-tools/downloads
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- El link de oracle no carga https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/library/eclipse-glassfish-tools-1.0.0

Siempre sale error y no deja configurar un server ni de glasfish, ni payara

Answer (score 0):

Para usar el servidor de glasfish 5.1

1. Descarga el servidor de glasfish que desee utilizar
2. Descraga el plugin de payara tools desde el github, el cual es un zip, no descomprimir -> Descarga en https://github.com/payara/ecosystem-eclipse-plugin/releases
3. Instala de forma manual el plugin *windows* -> *new Software* -> *add*
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Ya instalado debe aparecer
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Se debe seleccionar la version la carpeta donde esta el glasfish y la version del JDK requerida